# How to properly size custom controls in a table header using JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, javafx, kotlin, tableview

I have a custom table header in JavaFx like this:

```
    for (column in table.columns) {
        val typeButton = Button("x")
        val label = Label(column.text).also {
            it.styleClass.add("column-header-label")
        }
        val contextButton = Button("x")
        val graphic = HBox().also {
            it.styleClass.add("column-header-graphic")
            it.add(typeButton)
            it.add(label)
            it.add(contextButton)
        }
        column.graphic = graphic
    }
```

What I'm doing here is replacing the original text label with an `HBox` which holds two buttons and a label. I use css to hide the original label:

```
.data-table .column-header > .label  {
    -fx-content-display: graphic-only;
}

.column-header-graphic {
    -fx-alignment: center-left;
}

.column-header-label {
    -fx-label-padding: 0 10 0 10;
}
```

This works but my problem is that the label in the middle is clipped for some reason:

[image]

If I put this `HBox` somewhere outside of the table it is not truncated so there must be something amiss with the `TableColumn` itself.

If I double click the column then it sets a wrong size:

[image]

**How can I properly size this `HBox` so the label isn't truncated and it is not oversized either?**

Is this the right way to set custom table column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I properly size this HBox so the label isn't truncated and it is not oversized either?

*Background*

The label currently has a text overrun that is invoked when the space to display the label isn't big enough to display the label.  The behaviour that a label undertakes in this situation is governed by its [overrunStyle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/OverrunStyle.html) which is set by [label.setTextOverrun](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#setTextOverrun-javafx.scene.control.OverrunStyle-).  The default overrun style is to apply an ellipsis to the text (the `...` which you see in your images), which is configured by [ellipsisStringProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#ellipsisStringProperty) of the label.  This behaviour is not because the label is in a table column, but because it is in a constrained area where it cannot fully display itself at its preferred size.

*How to solve this*

From my understanding of your question, you actually don't want this default behaviour of applying an ellipsis to the text.  To prevent it, what you can do is to ensure that there is always adequate space to display the header (at least as far as the rendering engine is concerned).

To do this, for the hBox which you are configuring as the Labeled graphic, set its min width to its pref width:

```
hBox.setMinWidth(HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);
```

*Some Notes*

You can still resize the columns manually using the column divider controls.  If you do this, the default implementation will let you resize the columns smaller than the min width you just defined for the header graphic.  When that occurs the right-most column headers are painting over the excess display from the left column headers (preventing a garbled display).

The behaviour seems OK as long as you used a constrained resize policy.  But sometimes you don't want to do that.  For an unconstrained resize policy (the default), this can cause an issue when you size the column very small and have a large blank area to the right of the right-most column you have defined as the header of that blank area is not painted over.  To prevent this overflow, you can set a clip on the custom header fields which you have defined (see the example provided below to understand how to do this).

Also, if you sort a column, the sort arrow can display over your custom header if you size the column small (which is also not great).  One way around the weirdness with the sorting arrow is just to set resize to false for a given column, which may or may not work OK for your use-case.

> Is this the right way to set custom table column headers?

I don't have a general "right" solution for custom table column headers (as you can probably tell ;-)

---

Here is a sample program you can try out.  It's in Java because I can't speak Kotlin.

In the sample, I apply some CSS rules to set the alignment and content display of your custom header.

*alignment.css*

```
.buttontastic.column-header > .label {
    -fx-alignment: baseline-left;
    -fx-content-display: graphic-only;
    -fx-padding: 5px;
}
```

*TableWithButtonHeaders.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithButtonHeaders extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
        addHeaderButtons(firstNameCol);
        firstNameCol.setPrefWidth(160);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));


        TableView table = new TableView();
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        table.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams")
        ));
        table.setPrefSize(300, 200);


        Pane layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10;");
        layout.getChildren().addAll(table);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));

        stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(
                TableWithButtonHeaders.class.getResource(
                        "alignment.css"
                ).toExternalForm()
        );

        stage.show();
    }

    private void addHeaderButtons(TableColumn col) {
        Label label = new Label(col.getText());
        label.setStyle("-fx-padding: 5px;");
        HBox hBox = new HBox(new Button("X"), label, new Button("X"));
        hBox.setMinWidth(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(0,0, col.getWidth(), hBox.getHeight());
        col.widthProperty().addListener(observable -> clip.setWidth(col.getWidth()));
        hBox.heightProperty().addListener(observable -> clip.setHeight(hBox.getHeight()));
        hBox.setClip(clip);

        col.getStyleClass().add("buttontastic");
        col.setText(null);
        col.setGraphic(hBox);
    }

    public static class Person {
        private final SimpleStringProperty firstName;
        private final SimpleStringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public void setFirstName(String fName) {
            firstName.set(fName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public void setLastName(String fName) {
            lastName.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

Display with enough space for the custom header:

[image: sample output]

Display once you resize the first column smaller:

[image: smaller sample output]

Comment: This works if I don't have too many columns in the table but I sometimes have 20+ columns and in that case `TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` messes things up. I need the table to be scrollable (it is scrollable by default). How can I fix this?

Comment: I updated the solution to address this concern more comprehensively and updated the example to use an unconstrained resize policy.

Comment: That's a great writeup, thanks! I'll take a look at it tomorrow. I was a bit busy with Controlsfx today.